# Regex troubleshooting

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the following data.

Sample dataset

```
name ID: john
name ID: peter
```

I want to be able to extract out peter using a regex.

I'm only able to get john using this regex - name `ID:\s(.*?)\s`

but is not able to extract only peter out.

Comment: You can omit the `\s` at the end and you don't have to make the dot non greedy `name ID:\s(.*)` See https://regex101.com/r/WosCwF/1

Comment: Why only peter? What makes peter special? Why not john too?

Comment: It may be that this regex question has a duplicate somewhere, but it's not the one this question was closed against.

Answer (score -1):

If these are single line items, you could anchor the expressions to the line boundaries:

```
^ expression $
```

... will do that, so:

```
^name ID: (.*)$
```

Make sure your expression is using the Multi-Line flag. Since you haven't specified the language or regex library you're using, I'm not 100% sure what the syntax would be in your case.

For C# you can pass the `RegexOptions.Multiline` to the constructor of the regex. In JavaScript you use the `/expression/m` syntax to set this option. In some libraries you can add `(?m:)` to the start of the expression.

Comment: What's with the -1?